# significantly more down-regulated genes than up-regulated genes

Tags: r, probability, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I would like to test if my dataset has significantly more down-regulated genes than up-regulated genes.

In my set of significant genes (BH-corrected) I have 20 up-regulated genes and 69 down-regulated genes. 
In the whole dataset I have 6820 up-regulated genes and 7568 down-regulated genes.

What test should I use to check if among the significant genes, there is more down-regulated genes that up-regulated genes, compared to the whole dataset? I tried MacNemar test:

```
performance <-  matrix(c(20, 6820, 69, 7568),
         nrow = 2,
         dimnames = list("sign" = c("yes", "no"),
                         "non-sign" = c("up", "down")))
mcnemar.test(Performance)
```

Result:

```
    McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction

data:  Performance
McNemar's chi-squared = 16.818, df = 1, p-value = 4.115e-05
```

Did I set up the test correct?